# How to add and merge values from different array of hashes in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
array_of_hash1 = 
    [{"Date" => "2019-07-01", "Country" => "US", "Email" => "sample1@gmail.com", "Price" => "11.224323", "Tax" => "8.55443"},
     {"Date" => "2019-07-01", "Country" => "US", "Email" => "sample2@gmail.com", "Price" => "16.664323", "Tax" => "6.55443"},
     {"Date" => "2019-06-30", "Country" => "US", "Email" => "sample3@gmail.com", "Price" => "17.854323", "Tax" => "7.12343"},
     {"Date" => "2019-07-02", "Country" => "UK", "Email" => "sample4@gmail.com", "Price" => "14.224323", "Tax" => "4.32443"}]

array_of_hash2 = 
    [{"Date" => "2019-07-01", "Name" => "John", "Price" => "11.3442223", "Tax" => "3.44343"},
     {"Date" => "2019-07-01", "Name" => "Jack", "Price" => "14.332323", "Tax" => "5.41143"},
    {"Date" => "2019-07-02", "Name" => "Sam", "Price" => "10.2223443", "Tax" => "2.344552"}]
```

Above are my inputs in array of hashes

1. Add Price and Tax in array_of_hash1 by Date
2. Add Price and Tax in array_of_hash2 by Date
3. Subtract as (i) - (ii)
4. If there are no values in array_of_hash2 by Date compare with array_of_hash1. Then take values from array_of_hash1 only.

Here is my expected output.

Expected Output:

```
[{"Date" => "2019-07-01", "Country" => "US", "Email" => "sample1@gmail.com", "Price" => "2.2121007000000006", "Tax" => "6.254"}, 
 {"Date" => "2019-07-02", "Country" => "UK", "Email" => "sample4@gmail.com", "Price" => "4.0019787", "Tax" => "1.9798780000000002"},
{"Date" => "2019-06-30", "Country" => "US", "Email" => "sample3@gmail.com", "Price" => "17.854323", "Tax" => "7.12343"}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using two helper methods for a DRY code and using [Enumerable#sum](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-sum), [Enumerable#group_by](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by), [Hash#merge](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Hash.html#method-i-merge), [Hash#transform_values](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Hash.html#method-i-transform_values) and also other methods you can find in the documentation.

I'm using also [Object#then](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Object.html#method-i-then) here.

```
def sum_price_tax(ary)
  ary.first.merge ary.then { |ary| { "Price" => ary.sum { |h| h["Price"].to_f }, "Tax" => ary.sum { |h| h["Tax"].to_f} }  }
end

def group_and_sum(array_of_hash)
  array_of_hash.group_by { |h| h["Date"] }.transform_values { |ary| sum_price_tax(ary) }
end
```

After the methods are defined, you can do:

```
a1 = group_and_sum(array_of_hash1)
a2 = group_and_sum(array_of_hash2)
a1.map { |k, v| v.merge(a2[k] || {}) { |h, old_val, new_val| old_val.is_a?(Float) ? old_val - new_val : old_val  } }

#=> [{"Date"=>"2019-07-01", "Country"=>"US", "Email"=>"sample1@gmail.com", "Price"=>2.2121007000000006, "Tax"=>6.254, "Name"=>"John"}, {"Date"=>"2019-06-30", "Country"=>"US", "Email"=>"sample3@gmail.com", "Price"=>17.854323, "Tax"=>7.12343}, {"Date"=>"2019-07-02", "Country"=>"UK", "Email"=>"sample4@gmail.com", "Price"=>4.0019787, "Tax"=>1.9798780000000002, "Name"=>"Sam"}]
```

In this way also the `"Name"` is present.

---

One way you could get rid of `"Name"` is using [Object#tap](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Object.html#method-i-tap) and [Hash#delete](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Hash.html#method-i-delete):

```
a1.map { |k, v| v.merge(a2[k] || {}) { |h, old_val, new_val| old_val.is_a?(Float) ? old_val - new_val : old_val  }.tap { |h| h.delete("Name") } }

#=> [{"Date"=>"2019-07-01", "Country"=>"US", "Email"=>"sample1@gmail.com", "Price"=>2.2121007000000006, "Tax"=>6.254}, {"Date"=>"2019-06-30", "Country"=>"US", "Email"=>"sample3@gmail.com", "Price"=>17.854323, "Tax"=>7.12343}, {"Date"=>"2019-07-02", "Country"=>"UK", "Email"=>"sample4@gmail.com", "Price"=>4.0019787, "Tax"=>1.9798780000000002}]
```

Comment: I need final result should have Date, Price, Tax columns. All other columns are not needed.

Comment: I see some Date values are nil in the final result

Comment: I have used like this to get only Date, Price, Tax columns and fix null values in Date. Is this a better way do this? a1.map { |k,v| v.merge(a2[k] || {}) { |h, old_val, new_val|   
  if old_val.is_a? Float
    old_val - new_val    
  elsif old_val == new_val
    old_val
  end } }.map do |hash| 
    hash.select{|k,v|
      ("Date" "Price" "Tax").include? k}
    end

Comment: If the inputs are csv string instead of array of hashes. Will it be better and faster to do the above merge in Ruby on Rails?

Comment: Let me know you suggestions on the above question

Comment: My Inputs are always csv. I am converting csv to array of hashes and doing the transformations such as merging like above question, adding/removing columns like this https://stackoverflow.com/q/54965593/1381266 and then convert back to csv from array of hashes. Will it be better to do transformations on csv instead of conversion between csv and array of hashes?

Comment: I suppose the intermediate objects to be handled are still `Array` and `Hash`. I guess it is possible make some improvements. Consider to post a new question, where you have raw `csv` input and expected `csv` output. Better to add also some try.

Answer (score 1):

We are given the following (simplified from the arrays given in the question and with one hash added to `arr2`):

```
arr1 = [ 
  {"Date"=>"2019-07-01", "Country"=>"US", "Price"=>"11.22", "Tax"=>"8.55"},
  {"Date"=>"2019-07-01", "Country"=>"US", "Price"=>"16.66", "Tax"=>"6.55"},
  {"Date"=>"2019-06-30", "Country"=>"US", "Price"=>"17.85", "Tax"=>"7.12"},
  {"Date"=>"2019-07-02", "Country"=>"UK", "Price"=>"14.22", "Tax"=>"4.32"}
]

arr2 = [
  {"Date"=>"2019-07-01", "Price"=>"11.34", "Tax"=>"3.44"},
  {"Date"=>"2019-07-01", "Price"=>"14.33", "Tax"=>"5.41"},
  {"Date"=>"2019-07-02", "Price"=>"10.22", "Tax"=>"2.34"},
  {"Date"=>"2019-07-03", "Price"=>"14.67", "Tax"=>"3.14"}
]
```

We will need a list of dates that are values of `"Date"` in the hashes in `arr1`.

```
dates1 = arr1.map { |g| g["Date"] }.uniq
  #=> ["2019-07-01", "2019-06-30", "2019-07-02"]
```

Now convert `arr2` to an array of those elements `h` in `arr2` for which `h["Date"]` is in `dates1`, with all keys other than `"Price"` and `"Tax"` removed from each hash retained, and with the values of those two keys converted to string representations of their values negated:

```
a2 = arr2.each_with_object([]) do |g,arr| arr <<
  { "Date"=>g["Date"], "Price"=>"-" << g["Price"], "Tax" =>"-" << g["Tax"] } if
    dates1.include?(g["Date"])
end
  #=> [{"Date"=>"2019-07-01", "Price"=>"-11.34", "Tax"=>"-3.44"},
  #    {"Date"=>"2019-07-01", "Price"=>"-14.33", "Tax"=>"-5.41"},
  #    {"Date"=>"2019-07-02", "Price"=>"-10.22", "Tax"=>"-2.34"}]
```

We now loop over all elements of `arr1` and `a2` to create hash with keys the values of `"Date"`, with values of `"Price"` and `"Tax"` aggregated. Once that is done we extract the value of the hash that has been constructed.

```
(arr1 + a2).each_with_object({}) do |g,h|
  h.update(g["Date"]=>g) do |_,merged_hash,hash_to_merge|
    merged_hash.merge(hash_to_merge) do |k,merged_str,str_to_merge| 
      ["Price", "Tax"].include?(k) ? "%.2f" %
        (merged_str.to_f + str_to_merge.to_f) : merged_str
    end
  end
end.values
  #=> [{"Date"=>"2019-07-01", "Country"=>"US", "Price"=>"2.21",  "Tax"=>"6.25"},
  #    {"Date"=>"2019-06-30", "Country"=>"US", "Price"=>"17.85", "Tax"=>"7.12"},
  #    {"Date"=>"2019-07-02", "Country"=>"UK", "Price"=>"4.00",  "Tax"=>"1.98"}]
```

In this last step the receiver of `values` is found to be the hash:

```
{"2019-07-01"=>{"Date"=>"2019-07-01", "Country"=>"US",
                "Price"=>"2.21", "Tax"=>"6.25"},
 "2019-06-30"=>{"Date"=>"2019-06-30", "Country"=>"US",
                "Price"=>"17.85", "Tax"=>"7.12"},
 "2019-07-02"=>{"Date"=>"2019-07-02", "Country"=>"UK",
                "Price"=>"4.00", "Tax"=>"1.98"}}
```

Notice that the result would be the same if `arr[1]["Country"]=>"Canada"`. I've assumed that would not be a problem or could not occur.

The last step uses versions of the methods [Hash#update](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html#method-i-update) (a.k.a. `merge!`) and [Hash#merge](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html#method-i-merge) that employ a hash to determine the values of keys that are present in both hashes being merged.

The values of the block variables (`|_,merged_hash,hash_to_merge|` and `|k,merged_str,str_to_merge|`) are explained in the docs. The first block variable is the common key (`_` and `k`). I've represented the first of these with an underscore to signal to the reader that it is not used in the block calculation (a common convention). The second block variable is the value of the key in the hash being built (`merged_hash` and `merged_str`). The third block variable is the value of the key in the hash being merged (`merged_hash` and `str_to_merge`).